# difference between setting up pointer with address-of operator

Tags: c, pointers, addressof

I wondered what is the big difference between setting up C pointers in this way:

```
int int_var = 5;
int *int_ptr = &int_var;
```

And this way:

```
int int_var = 5;
int *int_ptr = int_var;
```

Since in both cases the result of `*int_ptr` will be 5, no?

Comment: *in both cases the result of *int_ptr will be 5, no?* No.

Comment: In the second case, `*int_ptr` will be whatever is stored at memory address 5. In other words, garbage.

Comment: Hint: turn up the warning level on your compiler and/or pay attention to the warning you're already getting ;).

Comment: Do you use `gcc`? Then activate all warnings: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`. This should already tell you that there is something smelly going on.

Comment: @jpm It's more likely the OS will catch it as an invalid access since such low addresses are rarely mapped.

Comment: @cnicutar In a sane run time, probably, but it's not guaranteed, so a crash (probably segfault) will be the best case scenario upon a dereference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, only in the first case. The second case will cause undefined behavior when you'll try to deference the pointer. Use the first case.

Some explanation:

```
int int_var = 5;
int *int_ptr = &int_var; // here int_ptr will hold the address of var
```

Whereas

```
int int_var = 5;
int *int_ptr = int_var; // here int_ptr will hold the address 5.
```

Comment: Ok, does this apply to arrays as well?

Comment: @arielschon12 What do you mean?

Comment: Should i write code like this:
`int array[20]; int *ptr=array;`
or with the address of operator?

Comment: @arielschon12: You _can_ write code like this, because `int[20]` can decay to `int*`. You _shouldn't_, as long as you don't know what you're actually doing.

Comment: @arielschon12 Depends on what you're trying to achieve. It won't copy anything (if that's what you expect to happen).

Comment: @Zeta It is perfectly fine to write code like this for purposes such as iterating over an array.

Answer (score 0):

No. In first case 5, in second case is undefined, is the conten of the memmory with adress 5. ??

Answer (score 0):

No the `int_ptr` is a pointer so you have to assign an address to it when you define it

The first is the right one

```
int int_var = 5;
int *int_ptr = &int_var;
```

the other is wrong

the other one you are assigning an int value `5` to the pointer `int_ptr` (address) so it's like you assign `5` as address for the pointer `int_ptr`

Answer (score 0):

In C, `pointers` point to the address itself. The address-of `&` operator is where the address of the variable is.

So in:

```
int int_var = 5;
int *int_ptr = &int_var;
```

***int_ptr** would correctly be used since it is pointed to the `ADDRESS` of int_var which has the value of 5

However in:

```
int int_var = 5;
int *int_ptr = int_var;
```

***int_ptr** points to an address that is 5, NOT the address where value 5 is located, which would be some random number.

**In addition** about arrays:

```
char *y;
char x[100];
y = x;
```

This can be done since an array is actually an address.

[For more information.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ansi_c/c_pointing_data.htm)